# Error pod installing on new macbook pro M1

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, gemspecs

I'm currently getting this issue when trying to pod install on my new macbook pro M1.

Version: 12.0 (21A344)

```
    end
    ^~~
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from /usr/local/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'
        1: from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:297:in `activate_bin_path'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:278:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem cocoapods (>= 0.a) with executable pod (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
```

Comment: you have to install cocoapod in your project

Comment: @MeisamSaba i get the same error when attempting to install pods

Comment: your first step have to solve installing pods

Answer (score 0):

Check your firebase library and make it compatible according to your version and check it.

Then delete pods and install them again.